# Limits in fetching instagram images

Tags: php, instagram

Iam using the following code to fetch the instagram images. Its working fine and it fetches all images from the corresponding instragram account. I need only 4 images to be displayed which is uploaded last. Can i apply limit to the following code.

```
<?php
function fetchData($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $result;
     }
     $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/00000/media/recent/?access_token=0000111111100000");
     $result = json_decode($result);
foreach ($result->data as $post) {

    ?>
<a href="#"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you echo $result and post the json here? Impromptu I´d say you could just $counter = count($result); for($i=$counter-4; $i<=$counter; i++) { <a href="#"><img src="<?= $result[$i]->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Count parameter to limit the number of images returned. Try:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/00000/media/recent/?access_token=0000111111100000&count=4
```